# Assign the name of the variable to a non NA in a data frame with multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop, sapply

For example, my df is:

```
         >dfABy 
         A    B     C

         56   NA  NA
         NA   45  NA
         NA   77  NA 
         67   NA  12 
         NA   65  3
```

I want to achieve the following data frame

```
         >dfABy 
         A    B    C

         A    NA  NA
         NA   B   NA
         NA   B   NA 
         A    NA  C
         NA   B   C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option in `base R`.  Convert the data into a logical matrix with TRUE for non-NA and FALSE for NA.  Replicate the column names based on the `col`um index ('nm1'). Assign the elements in the data based on the index 'i1' with the corresponding column names

```
i1 <- !is.na(dfABy)
nm1 <- names(dfABy)[col(dfABy)]
dfABy[i1] <- nm1[i1]
```

-output

```
dfABy
#     A    B    C
#1    A <NA> <NA>
#2 <NA>    B <NA>
#3 <NA>    B <NA>
#4    A <NA>    C
#5 <NA>    B    C
```

---

Or in a single line

```
dfABy[] <- names(dfABy)[col(dfABy)][(NA^is.na(dfABy)) * col(dfABy)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
dfABy %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., !is.na(.), cur_column())))
#     A    B    C
#1    A <NA> <NA>
#2 <NA>    B <NA>
#3 <NA>    B <NA>
#4    A <NA>    C
#5 <NA>    B    C
```

#### data

```
dfABy <- structure(list(A = c(56L, NA, NA, 67L, NA), B = c(NA, 45L, 77L, 
NA, 65L), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 12L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative is to use the `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)
 
df <- data.frame(A = c(56, NA, NA, 67, NA), B = c(NA, 45, 77, NA, 65), C = c(NA, NA, NA,12, 3))
 
imap_dfc(df, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), NA, .y))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     NA    NA   
2 NA    B     NA   
3 NA    B     NA   
4 A     NA    C    
5 NA    B     C
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option with `Map` :

```
dfABy[] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, y), dfABy, names(dfABy))
dfABy

#     A    B    C
#1    A <NA> <NA>
#2 <NA>    B <NA>
#3 <NA>    B <NA>
#4    A <NA>    C
#5 <NA>    B    C
```